# Why my Spark Direct stream is sending multiple offset commits to Kafka?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

> **I am running the following code in Spark**

```
  val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster("local[*]")
    .setAppName("KafkaTest")
    .set("spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition","10")
    .set("spark.default.parallelism","10")
    .set("spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled", "true")
    .set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")

  lazy val sparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
  val sparkJob = new SparkLocal

  val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
      "bootstrap.servers" -> "kafka-270894369.spark.google.com:9092",
      "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "group.id" -> "stream_group1",
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
      "enable.auto.commit" -> "false",
      "heartbeat.interval.ms" -> "130000", //3000
      "request.timeout.ms" -> "150000", //40000
      "session.timeout.ms" -> "140000", //30000
      "max.poll.interval.ms" -> "140000", //isn't a known config
      "max.poll.records" -> "100" //2147483647
    )

    val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(sparkContext, Seconds(120))

    val topics = Array("topicname")

    val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
      streamingContext,
      PreferConsistent,
      Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
    )

    def messageTuple(tuple: ConsumerRecord[String, String]): (String) = {
      (null) // Removed the code
    }

    var offset : Array[OffsetRange] = null

    kafkaStream.foreachRDD{rdd =>
      val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
      offset = offsetRanges

      rdd.map(row => messageTuple(row))
        .foreachPartition { partition =>
          partition.map(row => null)
            .foreach{ record =>
              print("")
              Thread.sleep(5)
            }
          }
      kafkaStream.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(offsetRanges)
      }

    streamingContext.start()
    streamingContext.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(6000000)

    sys.ShutdownHookThread{
      println("Gracefully shutting down App")
      streamingContext.stop(true,true)
      println("Application stopped")
    }
```

> **With the above code I am observing multiple commits are sending to Kafka and I am not sure why ?**
>
> *(Got the below from __consumer_offset topic)*

```
[stream_group1,topicname,59]::OffsetAndMetadata(offset=864006531, leaderEpoch=Optional.empty, metadata=, commitTimestamp=1577730000011, expireTimestamp=Some(1577816400011))
[stream_group1,topicname,59]::OffsetAndMetadata(offset=864006531, leaderEpoch=Optional.empty, metadata=, commitTimestamp=1577730000012, expireTimestamp=Some(1577816400012))
[stream_group1,topicname,59]::OffsetAndMetadata(offset=864005827, leaderEpoch=Optional.empty, metadata=, commitTimestamp=1577730000079, expireTimestamp=Some(1577816400079))

[stream_group1,topicname,59]::OffsetAndMetadata(offset=864008524, leaderEpoch=Optional.empty, metadata=, commitTimestamp=1577730120008, expireTimestamp=Some(1577816520008))
[stream_group1,topicname,59]::OffsetAndMetadata(offset=864008524, leaderEpoch=Optional.empty, metadata=, commitTimestamp=1577730120010, expireTimestamp=Some(1577816520010))
[stream_group1,topicname,59]::OffsetAndMetadata(offset=864008524, leaderEpoch=Optional.empty, metadata=, commitTimestamp=1577730120077, expireTimestamp=Some(1577816520077))

[stream_group1,topicname,59]::OffsetAndMetadata(offset=864008959, leaderEpoch=Optional.empty, metadata=, commitTimestamp=1577730240010, expireTimestamp=Some(1577816640010))
[stream_group1,topicname,59]::OffsetAndMetadata(offset=864008959, leaderEpoch=Optional.empty, metadata=, commitTimestamp=1577730240015, expireTimestamp=Some(1577816640015))
[stream_group1,topicname,59]::OffsetAndMetadata(offset=864008959, leaderEpoch=Optional.empty, metadata=, commitTimestamp=1577730240137, expireTimestamp=Some(1577816640137))
```

> Ideally we should see only one commit for every 2mins based on my
>   batch size but in our case we are observing 3 commits.
>
> Also during the Application restart we are loosing the data because of
>   above issue (Commit mismatch)
>
> Please help me with your inputs ?

Comment: Why not use Structured Streaming?

Comment: This is an existing code, so I am debugging to find the root cause of the issue.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? What behavior is wrong other than over population of the offsets topic? Without stating that, I feel like you're looking at the wrong thing

Comment: My issue is we are loosing data because of that during restart..... Every 2mins we are seeing 3 commits for example 1000,2000,3000 ...If our spark processed only 1000 messages then we are loosing data from offsets 2000-3000

Answer (score 0):

You're committing offsets within a forEachRDD. You should see 1 commit literally "for each RDD" , and it appears you had at least three

Comment: Hi cricket-007, I think eachRDD is like a 2min batch and after processing all the messages within that batch the app should send one commit to Kafka...So we should have only one commit within 2min window.

Comment: @RB7 , "eachRDD" is not for each 2-mins window, "eachRDD" depends on number of partitions within each window. So cricket's answer is correct

Comment: @Remis Haroon, Thanks for the response ..... But in my case I have 100 partitions and also the 3 commits are happening in 2mins for each partition....the above offsets are just for partition 59.

Comment: @RB7 I think Remis means *Spark partitions*, not Kafka

Comment: println(rdd.partitions.length) = 100

Comment: And we are committing outside of "foreachPartition" loop so which means one commit for every batch